# Using Anvil to send images to collab and saving them

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, google-colaboratory

I'm using Anvil from anvil.works to send images to Google Colab  and then transforming them. But I want to save the file first. This is how I've opened the image.

```
image1 = Image.open(io.BytesIO(image_1.get_bytes()))
```

What can I do to save it as "test.png" to Colab's content folder?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
image1.save("test.png")
```